# gcc exec if and else too... is this a bug?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

## Using gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

when using if else statements on pointer a:

```
if(a==NULL)
    ....
else
   .....
```

both are executed. Can someone explain me?

here part of code that implements a dinamic list with malloc c/c++ function.

## compiling the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct simplelist {int v;struct simplelist *ptr;};
void push(simplelist &s,int value);
void printlist(simplelist &s);

int main()
{
struct simplelist list; list.ptr=NULL;
push(list,1); push(list,2); push(list,3); push(list,4);
int v=0; v=getsize(list); cout<<"size: "<<v<<endl;
return 0;
}
void push(simplelist &s,int v)
{
if (s.ptr==NULL)
{
    s.v=v;
    s.ptr=(simplelist *) malloc(sizeof(simplelist));
    if(s.ptr==NULL) cout<<"out of memory"<<endl; 
}
else
    push(*s.ptr,v);
}

int getsize(simplelist &s)
{
int v=1;
if (s.ptr==NULL)
    {
        v--;
        cout<<"getsize s.ptr=null"<<endl; //here bug?
    }                                     //program exec if and else statement

else
{
    v=v+getsize(*s.ptr);
    cout<<"getsize elsewere"<<endl;
}


return v;
}
```

I got the output:

```
getsize s.ptr=null
getsize elsewere
getsize elsewere
getsize elsewere
getsize elsewere
```

Comment: Yes, `else'` doesn't look real.

Comment: And you probably should use existing [C++ containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/).

Comment: just removed ' it was an error reporting the original

Comment: Your `getsize` is called multiple times, so yes, it can then happen that some of those times the `if` condition is true, and other times it isn't true.

Comment: Please edit your code until it is something that compiles as is (currently, ' is not the only problem, getsize is not declared before being used).

Comment: containers are a way. But the problems about if else looks to be still there

Comment: the frist time it use the if condition... so it should stop. but it run the else too

Comment: There is no problem with how GCC implements `else`, you just don't understand what your code does. Try walking through it using a debugger before assuming one of the world's most widely-used compilers can't get `if`/`else` right. [The first rule of programming: it's always your fault](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: I saw that when you use a recursive function in gcc it bufferize again and again the function till the base function, then the base function is executed, and so on the ones before. it is not a bug sorry. I think we can close this discussion. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your function just prints messages in the reverse order. (First message is related to the last element, and so on.)

```
else
{
    v=v+getsize(*s.ptr);
    cout<<"getsize elsewere"<<endl;
}
```

must be

```
else
{
    cout<<"getsize elsewere"<<endl;
    v=v+getsize(*s.ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to its recursive structure, `getsize()` prints out a line *for every node in your list*. The last node is printed first, and is the only node whose `ptr` is `NULL`.